# Como criar um Ranking em C?

Tags: c, arquivo, txt

Como posso ler e ordenar um arquivo texto onde as informações estão assim:

```
  carlos   5 
  lucas   20 
  josue   10
```

*No arquivo fica assim.

Salvo de forma aleatória mas quando vou ler a informação preciso que seja na ordem de quem tem mais pontos para menos pontos.

Utilizo o seguinte código para ler o arquivo em si :

```
void ranking(){         



     system("cls");
     printf("\n ######- Ranking de Jogadores -######\n");
     printf("  \n");
     printf(" NOME - PONTOS \n");
     printf("  \n");
     printf(" ");


  char texto_str[999];
  char usuario[20];

  //abrindo o arquivo_frase em modo "somente leitura"
  pont_arq = fopen("ranking.txt", "r");

 while(fgets(texto_str, 20, pont_arq) != NULL)
 printf("%s \n ", texto_str);



  fclose(pont_arq);

  getch();

system("PAUSE");
carregaMenu();
```

}

Comment: Poste a estrutura do seu arquivo, assim poderemos te ajudar

Comment: tudo na mesma linha?

Comment: Não não . acertei ali no post agr. Com espaços e tudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para você obter os nomes e pontuação, como o tamanho dos caracteres de nome e de pontuação são diferentes, podemos utilizar o fscanf para realizar essa tarefa.
Teriamos por exemplo:

```
fscanf(pont_arq, "%s %d\n", nome, &pontuacao);
```

Quanto a ordenação teriamos várias maneiras de realizar essa tarefa.
Acho que a maneira mais correta seria você criar uma estrutura de dados de lista de prioridade e um struct de jogadores, inserindo eles de maneira já ordenada nesta lista. Você poderia também adicionar na lista de qualquer maneira e utilizar um algoritmo de ordenação (sort) como bubblesort, heapsort, quicksort, utilizando como parâmetro de ordenação a pontuação.

Outra maneira talvez mais simples só que menos organizada seria você trabalhar com um vetor de nomes, outro vetor com as pontuações correspondentes aos nomes e assim ordenar os dois vetores utilizando a pontuação como parametro da ordenação.

Vou realizar uma implementação da ultima opção citada pelo fato de ser a mais simples. Utilizei também como algoritmo de ordenação o bubblesort. Resolvi fazer de maneira estática, mas caso não seja possível definir o tamanho de linhas do arquivo utilize malloc para realizar a instanciação dinâmica dos jogadores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//algoritmo de sort, perceba que aqui eu ordeno os dois vetores (nome e pontuação)

void bubbleSort(int* pontuacao, char nomes[10][255], int tamanho)
{   
    int i;
    int trocou;
    do  
    {
        trocou = 0;
    for (i=tamanho; i > 0; i--)
    {   
        if (pontuacao[i] > pontuacao[i-1]) 
        {   
            int pAux;
            char nAux[255];
            pAux = pontuacao[i];
            strcpy(nAux, nomes[i]);
            pontuacao[i] = pontuacao[i-1];
            strcpy(nomes[i], nomes[i-1]);
            pontuacao[i-1] = pAux;
            strcpy(nomes[i-1], nAux);
            trocou = 1;
        }   
    }   

    }while (trocou);
}   



void ranking(){         

    //system("clear");
    printf("\n ######- Ranking de Jogadores -######\n");
    printf("  \n");
    printf(" NOME - PONTOS \n");
    printf("  \n");

    // cria ponteiro de arquivo
    FILE * pont_arq;
    //abrindo o arquivo_frase em modo "somente leitura"
    pont_arq = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    // cria matriz para 10 nomes (poderia ser dinamico) e array de pontuações
    char nomes[10][255];
    int pontuacoes[10];
    //variaveis que irá receber o nome ea pontuação do arquivo
    char nome[255];
    int pontuacao;
    //quantidade de jogadores
    int tamanho = 0;

    //lê do arquivo
    while(fscanf(pont_arq, "%s   %d\n", nome, &pontuacao) != EOF)
    {   
        strcpy(nomes[tamanho],nome);
        pontuacoes[tamanho] = pontuacao;
        tamanho++;  
    }

    //Ordena
    bubbleSort(pontuacoes, nomes, tamanho);

    //Imprime
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", nomes[i], pontuacoes[i]);
    }

  fclose(pont_arq);

  //getch();

//system("PAUSE");
//carregaMenu();

}
```

Comment: Deu tudo certo. Obrigado !